# Linker error: CFHTTP request methods in libShareKit.a on Xcode 4.5 and ShareKit 2.0

Tags: facebook, ios6, sharekit, xcode4.5, fbrequest-form

I try to intergrate the sharekit 2.0 into my app and installed the new ShareKit 2.0 as a Submodule in my local Git repository. I think I've followed the install instructions properly, but I'm getting 18 linker errors on the '`smoke test`'.

Here some error:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture i386:
  "_CFHTTPMessageCopyHeaderFieldValue", referenced from:
      -[LFHTTPRequest(PrivateMethods) readStreamHasBytesAvailable] in libShareKit.a(LFHTTPRequest.o)
      -[LFHTTPRequest(PrivateMethods) readStreamEndEncountered] in libShareKit.a(LFHTTPRequest.o)
```

I have included `libShareKit.a` under '`Link Binary with Libraries`' in the Build Phases as indicated in the directions. It is showing up red, if that means anything.

Help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please add CFNetwork, CoreLocation and Twitter frameworks and rebuild your application.

Comment: In my case this solution reduced the amount of errors by 15, but why I had to do this? CFNetwork is for flickr and I don't need it for my app...

Comment: Reference may be still there to these Apis.